# Renaming default category taxonomy?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Is it possible to rename the default "Category" to any certain name? Like Example: "Genre"? So that the permalink will be 127.0.0.1/genre/action/

Or creating a new taxonomy category is the only option?

Comment: If you only need to change the permalinks, you can set *Category Base* to `genre` under *Settings > Permalinks*.

Comment: @Milo thanks! but is it possible to change permalinks through functions/codes so if the theme gets activated, the category's set to to genre already.

Comment: `category_base` is [stored in an option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) that you can update.